# Multiplying in angular4 component.ts

Tags: angular

main.component.html file:

```
height: 
<input type="number" 
name="height"
[(ngModel)]="user.height">
<br><br>

Weight:
<input type="number" 
name="weight" 
[(ngModel)]="user.weight"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

main.component.ts file:

```
onSubmit(){

console.log(this.user.height);
console.log(this.user.weight);

var average = this.user.weight * this.user.height


this.user = {
height: '',
weight:''
} 

}
```

In main.component.ts file, when I try to multiply the height and weight values i get and error, 
**"The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type."**
How can i multiply the this.user.weight and this.user.height?

Comment: btw the console.log for height and weight works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think your problem is the TYPE of height and weight

what if you try this?

```
this.user = {
height: 0,
weight: 0
}
```

Cause your type is a string..i think it has to be a number

Comment: you wellcome..if it helped you rate it!! .. thnx!!